# Azure Event Hub / Topic / Queue Best Approach

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-servicebus-topics

If I have access to Azure Queues, Topics, and Event Hubs which is the best technology to use if I have one producer, and approximately 1000 subscribers? The message size would be less than 30k, and the amount would be no greater than 3000 per day.  I've read over the Azure docs, and it remains unclear what approach is best if I need all 1000 subscribers to all get the message once?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: `best` will depend heavily on your criteria. Is message delivery reliability essential? Do all consumers always get the same messages, or is custom filtering required? Is cost important? What latency requirements are needed? Does your solution need to scale to very high volumes? How long do you need to retain messages? Do consumers need to be able to re-read messages? etc.

Comment: Message delivery reliability would be essential, latency would not be an issue (i.e the message is pub'd now, but does not arrive for 10 mins would be acceptable) message retention no longer than a few days, and would not need to scale for high volumes, message count and consumer count would be reasonably static.

Answer (score 1):

For events with a large number of subscribers, I would look at [EventGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/overview) with a [custom topics/events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic). EventGrid can handle way more than a thousand subscribers, has low latency, reliable (retries up to 24 hours), and build for high throughput, allowing millions of events per second, region agnostic.